# Improving code with Java 8 Predicates - comparing multiple arguments

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, predicate

I'm not sure I have the right title.  I want to perform some validation on a request.  I have this conditional test in many places in my existing code.  It is located in a utility class.  The method is DoesRequestLineFallsWithinDateRange(object).

I'm wondering if I can improve the code and be more elegant with Java 8 by using Predicates and retire the method.

Processing a request:
I want to check each line if they meet a condition.  So the calling method calls this utility class to check if each line is within the data range.  In this example, is the item (requestLine) within the subscription period.

A request comes in, some processing adds a subscription member object to the request line.
Then the utility method is called on each line to check if the request line is within the subscription period.

The method first checks that the date fields it is supposed to use are not null first to prevent a null exception.

Then using the request line date, compares against the subscription members start/end date fields to determine if the dates are in range.

I'd like to replace the method with a Java 8 Predicate function call.

Here is a sample of the method that tests each line in the collection if it is within a data range.

```
public static boolean DoesRequestLineFallsWithinDateRange(RequestLine requestLine) {
    if (isDatesNotNull(requestLine)) {
      return requestLine.getServiceStartDate().compareTo(requestLine.getSubscription().getStartDate()) >= 0
          && requestLine.getServiceStartDate().compareTo(requestLine.getSubscription().getEndDate()) <= 0;
    }
   return false;
  }

public class RequestLine(){
   private Date serviceStartDate;
   private Subscription subscription;
.....

}
```

Comment: You should make the method a non-static no-arg method of class `RequestLine`, i.e. make it more than just a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

Comment: You are not showing how you're processing the whole request. Do you have a list of `RequestLine`? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code written using Java 8 `Predicates` and `LocalDate` API

```
    public boolean doesRequestLineFallsWithinDateRange(RequestLine requestLine)
    {
        BiPredicate<LocalDate, LocalDate> afterDatePredicate = (startData, endDate) -> (startData.isAfter(endDate));
        BiPredicate<LocalDate, LocalDate> beforeDatePredicate = (startData, endDate) -> (startData.isBefore(endDate));

        if (Objects.isNull(requestLine))
        {
            return false;
        }

        LocalDate serviceStartDate = requestLine.getServiceStartDate();
        LocalDate startDate = requestLine.getSubscription().getStartDate();
        LocalDate endDate = requestLine.getSubscription().getEndDate();

        return afterDatePredicate.test(serviceStartDate, startDate) && beforeDatePredicate.test(serviceStartDate,
                endDate);

    }
```

Referenced Java Code

**RequestLine.java**

```
public class RequestLine

{
    private Subscription subscription;
    private LocalDate serviceStartDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Subscritpion.java**

```
public class Subscription
{
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to integrate your code to use a method reference as predicate and filter a stream of RequestLine. The interesting method is `execute`: it receives a stream and filters it with a reference to doesRequestLineFallsWithinDateRange method.

```java
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class RequestLine {

    public void execute(Stream<RequestLine> stream) {
        // this is the interesting code
        stream.filter(this::doesRequestLineFallsWithinDateRange);
    }

    public boolean doesRequestLineFallsWithinDateRange(RequestLine requestLine) {
        if (isDatesNotNull(requestLine)) {
            return requestLine.getServiceStartDate().compareTo(requestLine.getSubscription().getStartDate()) >= 0
                    && requestLine.getServiceStartDate().compareTo(requestLine.getSubscription().getEndDate()) <= 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //code created to complete the example
    public static class Subscription {

        private Date startDate;

        public Date getEndDate() {
            return endDate;
        }

        private Date endDate;

        public Date getStartDate() {
            return  startDate;
        }
    }



    private boolean isDatesNotNull(RequestLine requestLine) {
        return requestLine.serviceStartDate!=null;
    }


    public Date getServiceStartDate() {
        return serviceStartDate;
    }

    public Subscription getSubscription() {
        return subscription;
    }

    private Date serviceStartDate;
    private Subscription subscription;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Predicate::and` to chain multiple predicates

```
Predicate<RequestLine> rlPred = this::isDatesNotNull;

rlPred = rlPred.and(p -> p.getServiceStartDate().compareTo(p.getSubscription().getStartDate()) >= 0)
               .and(p -> p.getServiceStartDate().compareTo(p.getSubscription().getEndDate()) <= 0);
```